How can a proxy be used in an Angular application on Heroku?
I have one angular application and one spring boot (backend) application. These applications are hosted as applications created with Heroku dashboard.
Backend api's base address: https://my_app.heroku.com/api
Example api endpoint: https://my_app.heroku.com/api/currentUser
Here is an example of the request I sent from the Angular application to the spring boot application:
getCurrentUser(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<any>(`/api/users/currentUser`);
}

I can send the above request successfully in my local environment with the following proxy settings. I can redirect requests starting with the address "/api/**" to "http://localhost:8080".
proxy.prod.conf.js
var winston = require("winston");

function logProvider() {
  return winston.createLogger({
    level: "debug",
    format: winston.format.combine(
      winston.format.splat(),
      winston.format.simple()
    ),
    transports: [new winston.transports.Console()],
  });
}

const PROXY_CONFIG = {
  "/api/**": {
    "target": "https://my_app.herokuapp.com",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "logProvider": logProvider,
    "bypass": function (req, res, proxyOptions) {
      if (req.headers.accept.indexOf("html") !== -1) {
        console.log("Skipping proxy for browser request.");
        return "/index.html";
      }
      req.headers["X-Custom-Header"] = "yes"; // adding oe setting header
      res.removeHeader('X-Header-Name'); //removing header
    }
  }
}

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;


proxy.conf.js
const winston = require("winston");

function logProvider() {
  return winston.createLogger({
    level: "debug",
    format: winston.format.combine(
      winston.format.splat(),
      winston.format.simple()
    ),
    transports: [new winston.transports.Console()],
  });
}


const PROXY_CONFIG = {
  "/api/**": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "logProvider": logProvider,
    "bypass": function (req, res, proxyOptions) {
      if (req.headers.accept.indexOf("html") !== -1) {
        console.log("Skipping proxy for browser request.");
        return "/index.html";
      }
      req.headers["X-Custom-Header"] = "yes"; // adding oe setting header
      res.removeHeader('X-Header-Name'); //removing header
    }
  }
}

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;


angular.json
...
...
...
"serve": {
   "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
     "configurations": {
        "production": {
           "browserTarget": "refque:build",
              "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.prod.conf.js"
           },
           "development": {
              "browserTarget": "refque:build:development",
              "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.js"
           }
        },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
    },
...
...
...

When I run it with the "ng serve" command in the local environment, the proxy works as I want, but in the Heroku prod environment, the proxy does not work because the "ng build --production" command runs instead of "ng serve".
Local log (successful proxy):

Heroku log(unsuccessful proxy)

I hope I was clear enough.
https://help.heroku.com/YTWRHLVH/how-do-i-make-my-nginx-proxy-connect-to-a-heroku-app-behind-heroku-ssl
Proxy Routing on Angular App deployed on Heroku
I tried the above guidances but was not successful.

Proxies like this are only for development. On Heroku, you should be compiling your Angular application to a production build so it can be served statically. That can be done from your Spring Boot application (if you want to host the application all together) or somewhere that's optimized for static hosting.

@Chris you are right. I solved my problem by installing Nginx. When I created the nginx.conf.erb file for Heroku in the /config directory in the main directory of the project and made the necessary settings, the proxy was successfully provided.
